# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when adding CSRF token to request headers plain JS

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to add CSRF token to request headers, but it returns the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

In my django template I have added {% csrf_token %} and my function looks like this:

```
addFavorites (id)  {
    return fetch(`/favorites`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
      },

...
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Right click and inspect the page. I tried the `document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value` and was able to get the token, make sure that it really is on the page and named that (it was for me)

Comment: @g23 Thanks, I was looking at another template by mistake :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you get back when you just run `document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')` by itself?

The issue is that there is nothing in the first index, or it's not returning an array. Therefore it's returning `undefined`. And since `undefined` doesn't have a value property, that's the error you're getting.

Comment: By mistake I was looking into another template :\ Thank you.

Comment: I wrote `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementsByName`. Now it works!